# d3.js group bar chart not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is my working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/wn6awvbe/ . Now this bar chart is working fine for `single value` and my requirement is to make it `group bar chart`.

So do this as a first step I have to create x-axis range based on `min` and `max` of all the values. I am able to do this successfully .

Second I tried to create a `group` and add individual `group bars` into the `group`. This part I am not able to crack.

Here is my code what I have tried

```
var combos = svg.selectAll("g").data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr({width: 2 * width})
    .attr('height',y.rangeBand()+10)
    ;

combos.selectAll(".bar1")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return "bar bar--" + (d.value < 0 ? "negative" : "positive"); })
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(Math.min(0, d.value)); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.name); })
  .attr("width", function(d) { return Math.abs(x(d.value) - x(0)); })
  .attr("height", y.rangeBand());

combos.selectAll(".bar2")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return "bar bar--" + (d.value < 0 ? "negative" : "positive"); })
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(Math.min(0, d.value1)); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.name); })
  .attr("width", function(d) { return Math.abs(x(d.value1) - x(0)); })
  .attr("height", y.rangeBand());
```

But for some reason its not working . What is the mistake I am doing here. Thanks for the help in Advance.

Comment: I got one mistake and updated my fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/wn6awvbe/1/, but still the bars are overlapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are always guaranteed to have 2 bars per group, a quick fix would be:

```
combos
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "ba ba--" + (d.value < 0 ? "negative" : "positive"); })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(Math.min(0, d.value)); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.name); })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return Math.abs(x(d.value) - x(0)); })
      .attr("height", y.rangeBand() / 2); //<-- cut height in half

  combos
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "bar bar--" + (d.value < 0 ? "negative" : "positive"); })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(Math.min(0, d.value1)); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.name) + (y.rangeBand() / 2); }) //<-- offset if from other bar
      .attr("width", function(d) { return Math.abs(x(d.value1) - x(0)); })
      .attr("height", y.rangeBand() / 2); //<-- cut height in 2
```

---

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wn6awvbe/2/).

**EDITS FOR COMMENTS**

If you want to have a dynamic number of bars, you really need to change your input data.  `value1:, value2:`, etc is just not workable.  A quick refactor might use an array of values:

```
{
  "name": "M1",
  "value": [-45, -13, -10, -8]
},
...
```

With this format you can use a sub-selection and really start getting some dynamic code:

```
var combos = svg.selectAll("g").data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g");    
combos
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d){
  return d.value.map(function(d1){
    return {
        value: d1,
        name: d.name,
        total: d.value.length,
      };
    })
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return "ba bar--" + (d.value < 0 ? "negative" : "positive"); })
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(Math.min(0, d.value)); })
  .attr("y", function(d,i) { return (y(d.name) + (y.rangeBand() / d.total * i)) ; })
  .attr("width", function(d) { return Math.abs(x(d.value) - x(0)); })
  .attr("height", function(d){
    return y.rangeBand() / d.total
   });
```

---

New updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wn6awvbe/3/).

Comment: Perfect @Mark . For the time being its 2 bars in a group :) Also could you please refer me some document link where I can get a sense of how to manage if `bars` in `group` more than 2

Comment: here you can see a document with grouped bar charts https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051

Comment: @curiousguy, see updated answer.  omartorres link is best way to do this, but my solution is a bit simpler based on your input data.